# How to check the PHP syntax in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse for developing PHP applications. I want to run PHP in lint mode to check the syntax of my PHP files for any errors. How can I do this within Eclipse? Thanks for any tipp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem: I worked with PHP files which were part of projects. Although I used the Eclipse PHP perspective there was no syntax checking. I found out that I had to configure the projetcs and add PHP support. Now its working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Install phpEclipse for all your syntax-checking needs :)

http://www.phpeclipse.com/

Answer (score 0):

see the pdt project (plugin)
http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

Comment: The "PHP Development Tools" are already installed but I don't know how to enable syntax checking...

Comment: switch to the php perspective and it should work out of the box.